# Android 4.3: ConstraintLayout inside ScrollView - incorrect margin

Tags: android

Android 4.3.

Here my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/shoppingDetailsScrollView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#aabbcc"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/contentContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:background="@color/place_holder_color">

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

As you can see I set **margin=20dp**

Here result:

[image: scrollView]

As you can see margin only on the left and top. But on bottom and right NO margin.

Why?

Comment: Why the inner ConstraintLayout has constraints inside the ScrollView? it is resolved for the parent and FrameLayout do ignores then

Comment: I tested your code. there was no problem and I saw the margin on left, right, bottom, and top.

Comment: I update my post. I remove constraint from inner ConstraintLayout, but this not help. Same result.

Comment: It's work on  Android 6.0+. But on Android 4.3. not work (no margin).